# Is is possible to redirect a function from one to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two ActiveRecord models:

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :fish_tank
end

class FishTank < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner

    def feed
        # do something
    end
end
```

I want to let an owner feed its fishtank. For now, I would create a function in the owner class that calls the feed class like:

```
def feed
    fish_tank.feed
end
```

Is it possible to redirect a function call to another model, something like:

```
has_many :something, through: :anything
```

Is there a cleaner, rails way to do this?

Comment: You mean delegate, not redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to let the owner feed the fishtank
>
> Is there an cleaner, rails way to do this?

Yes, you can use [*delegate*](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method. In the `FishTank` model

```
class FishTank < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner
  delegate :feed, to: :owner #add this line

  def feed
    # do something
  end
end
```

Now you can do `Owner.new.feed` to call the `feed` method

Comment: delegate method should be in `Owner` model